# Know location of friends near by you

Tags: android, blackberry, location

I am new in blackberry & android.
Is it possible to know the location of perticular cellphone number which is near by me in both blacberry as well as android.

I will be thankfull to your resonse.

Comment: A number?  No.  A device whose owner has installed software to participate in some location sharing service?  Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google provide a service called [Latitude](http://www.google.co.uk/latitude). There is no other legal non-creepy way of doing this that I know of.

Comment: You can use a web server to do this,When user takes the app send some info to webserver (including lat,long) and and retreives some info from webserver about others who using the app,You can try xml rpc

Comment: Yeah but would't sending someone's lat-lon over to some Webserver be illegal? *shrug* IANAL but I hope such information remains with trusted sources.